# How to change order of input statements on the same line?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner trying to create a dictionary with both keys and values that are inputs.

Trying `my_dict[input(x)]=input(y)` will prompt the y-input first, but is there a way to switch it so the x-input is the first prompt?

Comment: Could you not just take the inputs as variables and then pass them to the dict?

Comment: @mnestorov Haha thank you, a very simple solution it was

Comment: ```mydict = dict({input():input()})``` takes key as first input and value as the second input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where you can modify your script and put the two separate inputs into variables, you can do the following

```py
y = input()
x = input()

my_dict[x] = y
```